# How to get javascript/html Code as it is from a textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to achieve functionality to store adsense code into sql database. For that I have used `ajax:HtmlEditorExtender` on a textbox. now I am typing this code

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!-- google_ad_client = "ca-pub-*****"; /* 728x90, created 6/12/02 */ google_ad_slot = "****"; google_ad_width = 728; google_ad_height = 90; //--> </script> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead.googlesyndicaon.com/pead/show_ad.js"> </script>
```

now the problem is when the code is inserted to database, above code is converted as below.

```
    &lt;pre&gt;&lt;<span>script</span> <span>type</span>="<a>text/javascript</a>"&gt;&lt;!--
    <span></span>google_ad_client = "ca-pub-*****";
    <span></span>/* 728x90, created 6/12/02 */
    <span></span>google_ad_slot = "****";
    <span></span>google_ad_width = 728;
    <span></span>google_ad_height = 90;
    <span></span>//--&gt;
    <span></span>&lt;/<span>script</span>&gt;
    <span></span>&lt;<span>script</span> <span>type</span>="<a>text/javascript</a>"
    <span></span><span>src</span>="<a href="view-source:http://pagead.googlesyndicaon.com/pead/show_ad.js">
http://pagead.googlesyndicaon.com/pead/show_ad.js</a>"&gt;
    <span></span>&lt;/<span>script</span>&gt;&lt;/pre&gt;
```

Please help me out:

1. what should I do so that i can store the upper code as it is to database.
2. when the code is properly stored to database, which control is best suitable to show this ad.(I mean I want to show ad on another page.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the sanitizer? Just making sure. Why not use ckeditor?

Comment: @PaulZahra : using EnableSanitization="true" resolves my first problem. Thanks a lot. what should i do for my second problem.

Comment: @PaulZahra sorry for my blunder. using EnableSanitization="true" doesn't make difference. This is also surrounding <span> to each text like this. <span style="font&#x2D;size&#x3A;&#x20;18&#x2E;88888931274414px&#x3B;">script</span>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RE issue2: You could use a normal textbox and just decode the string, or put it back into a ajax:HtmlEditorExtender textbox, and use the following code (sanitizer has probably encoded all the tag start and ends etc...

```
Server.HtmlDecode(TextBox_Editor.Text)
```

In response to your comment: Try putting the decoded text into a asp:label OnPreRender

EDIT: Try using HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider, the latest pack which resolves some 'bugs' surrounding the sanitizer... have a read of [this page](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2012/06/25/announcing-the-june-2012-release-of-the-ajax-control-toolkit), by Stephen Walters own admission the default sanitizer is far too aggressive in what it strips.

Comment: I think u got me wrong. Actually I want to display the ad on different page, whose adsense-code comes from the database. So which control I should use so that retrieved code can displayed as ad.

Comment: thanks @PaulZahra the approach u suggested is really helping. thanks again.